# joomla language file not loading other languages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I've built a simple component that sends an email. Inside that component I have my translations strings stored in the ini. Here is some sample code of what I do:

```
$body = $this->getDetails["name"]." ".JText::_('COM_MYCOMPNOTIFY_MAIL_BODY1')."\n\n".
JText::_('COM_MYCOMPNOTIFY_MAIL_BODY2')." ".$this->getDetails["name"]."\n\n".
JText::_('COM_MYCOMPNOTIFY_MAIL_BODY3')." http://".$this->getDetails["domain"]."\n";
```

This directory structure I have for my component has

```
language
  en-GB
    en-GB.com_mycompnotify.ini
  pt-BR
    pt-BR.com_mycompnotify.ini
```

My install xml file has this:

```
<files folder="site">
        <filename>index.html</filename>
...
        <folder>helpers</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
</files>
```

This works fine for the `en-GB` language. But I can't get it to translate for `pt-BR`. I think the issue is that I have an external php file that calls my component. So it wouldn't know to load pt-BR language file (I think).

So I tried to force it to load:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_mycompnotify', JPATH_BASE, 'pt-BR'); //also tried JPATH_SITE
```

But no matter what I try I always get English.

Comment: You need to show the code at the point that it isn't working. Also make sure you've got your debug mode on, and error reporting turned all the way up to dev.

Answer (score 0):

for specifying language files in component xml file you should add somthing like this :

```
<languages folder="admin">
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_NAME.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_NAME.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="pt-BR">language/pt-BR/pt-BR.com_NAME.ini</language>
    <language tag="pt-BR">language/pt-BR/pt-BR.com_NAME.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

if you are developing a component `Not just for administrator` side only, you can add site languages files like this :

```
<languages folder="site">
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_NAME.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_NAME.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="pt-BR">language/pt-BR/pt-BR.com_NAME.ini</language>
    <language tag="pt-BR">language/pt-BR/pt-BR.com_NAME.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

and for joomla to use the language files which aren't english you should change site's language to your native language.You can download translations for many languages from joomla's official site.

Comment: What your suggesting is the same as just using `language` folder as I have. Thanks for the response but this doesn't help.

Comment: you should use <languages></languages> tag instead of <files></files>.make sure that when you install your component into joomla! the installer copies the language files into the correct path.

Comment: I use `<folder>language</folder>` instead as the documentation explains is the same. But at any rate I tried your suggestion and I still have the same problem. I have many components and they all are translating just fine except this one. I'm believe the problem is how I call the language file: `$lang->load('com_mycompnotify', JPATH_SITE, 'pt-BR', true);`. Something must be wrong with this.

Comment: Use of the <language> tag is deprecated as of Joomla 1.6, see http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Language_files